# How do I offset the value of a cell to another column?

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-analysis, data-cleaning, m

My goal is to drag over the value of a cell to the corresponding row in another column under a condition.

I have the following table:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | null |
| 27€ | null |
| 13 | null |

If the cell in Column1 contains a "€", then that cell should be emptied and the value brought to Column2.

The output should then be:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | null |
| null | 27€ |
| 13 | null |

The condition is pretty straight-forward, but I'm unfamiliar with the logic of the query editor and how to express the output.

(I'm aware that this can be easily done on Excel or with VBA, but I would like to know how to do these types of tasks directly with Query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another method with no added columns, using the `Table.TransformRows` function:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type any}}),
    
    #"Move €" = Table.FromRecords(
                    Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type", (r)=>
                        Record.TransformFields(r,  {
                            {"Column1", each if Text.EndsWith(_,"€") then null else _},
                            {"Column2", each if Text.EndsWith(r[Column1],"€") then r[Column1] else _}
                                                    }
                            )
                        )
                    )
in
    #"Move €"
```

[image]

Comment: In my attempt to create a reproducible example I oversimplified my concrete issue so that I'm having trouble getting the code to work on my query (I'm getting the error `We cannot convert the value null to type Logical` on the cells in `Column2` that aren't actually set to `null`). The code does work on the example I offered on the post though and I'll try to find a solution based on it.

Comment: @maliebina But I never test Column 2. Are you sure that is the issue? What is in Column 2?

Comment: Correction: both columns have cells with that error. The code works as expected with Column1 (the cells that contain a € are set to `null` and the original values are shifted to Column2) but on C2, the cells that *already* contained a € are set to `ERROR` instead of being ignored. The same error appears happens when I try a different approach (replacing the null values in both columns with Empty and merge the two columns). For some reason the rows change order after I run `Move €` and the table does have many duplicate values so it's difficult to say what exactly is happening.

Comment: I might make a separate post to better explain how the code is behaving with my table and what I've attempted so far.

Comment: @maliebina Yes, I think a question with a more realistic example would be in order. If I put values in column 2, they remain unchanged unless there is a `€` value in column 1, in which case the column 1 value is moved to column 2, and is blanked in column 1. Which is what you described. The contents of column 2 seems irrelevant and no errors are produced.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create two new columns and then delete the original two. e.g.

[image]

Add column - custom column:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your power query code should be like the below

```
let
    Source = [YourSourceHere], // Replace this with your actual source step
    AddedCustom2 = Table.AddColumn(Source, "New Column2", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "€") then null else [Column1]),
    AddedCustom1 = Table.AddColumn(AddedCustom2, "New Column1", each if Text.Contains([Column1], "€") then [Column1] else null),
    RemovedOriginals = Table.RemoveColumns(AddedCustom1, {"Column1", "Column2"}),
    RenamedColumns = Table.RenameColumns(RemovedOriginals, {{"New Column1", "Column1"}, {"New Column2", "Column2"}})
in
    RenamedColumns
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source cell is text, pre-append a | then split on that character

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
AddSplit = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1", each if Text.Contains(_,"€") then "|"&_ else _, type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(AddSplit, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"|"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"})
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]